# Templates :Name resolution -->can any one tell some more examples for this statement?

Tags: c++, templates

This is the statement from ISO C++ Standard 14.6/7:

> Knowing which names are type names
>   allows the syntax of every template
>   definition to be checked. No
>   diagnostic shall be issued for a
>   template    definition for which a
>   valid specialization can be generated.
>   If no valid    specialization can be
>   generated for a template definition,
>   and that   template is not
>   instantiated, the template definition
>   is ill-formed, no    diagnostic
>   required. If a type used in a
>   non-dependent name is incomplete   at
>   the point at which a template is
>   defined but is complete at the point
>   at which an instantiation is done, and
>   if the completeness of that type
>   affects whether or not the program is
>   well-formed or affects the semantics
>   of the program, the program is
>   ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.
>   [Note: if a template is
>   instantiated,errors will be diagnosed
>   according to    the other rules in
>   this Standard. Exactly when these
>   errors are diagnosed    is a quality
>   of implementation issue. ]

Example:

```
    int j;
    template<class T> class X {
               // ...
               void f(T t, int i, char* p)
               {
                                         // diagnosed if X::f is instantiated
                           t = i;
                                         // and the assignment to t is an error
                                         // may be diagnosed even if X::f is
                           p = i;
                                         // not instantiated
                                         // may be diagnosed even if X::f is
                           p = j;
                                         // not instantiated
               }
               void g(T t) {
                                         // may be diagnosed even if X::g is
                           +;
                                         // not instantiated
               }
    };
```

(mostly failed cases)
can any one tell some more examples for this statement ..like this..please?

Comment: I think that your whole approach about all this "check compilers standards compliance" is just plain wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void f<T>() "I am an ill-formed 'template definition' parameterized on T.";
```

An implementation is allowed to accept the above as a syntactically ill-formed template definition and not diagnose it until it's actually instantiated. Hope this explains it. (Of course I'm kidding, but I'm not entirely unserious. It shows a flaw of the above quoted text: There is no "template definition" that can contain ";+;").

The other thing about incomplete types says the following is ill-formed but no diagnostic is required

```
struct foo;

template<typename T>
void f() { foo x; }
  // foo is incomplete here

struct foo { };
  // foo is complete here

int main() { f<int>(); }
```

The "no diagnostic required" rules in the Standard grants an implementation to behave in any way it sees fit (this makes any program that violates a rule for which no diagnostic is required to have effectively undefined behavior). As a result, the text you quoted really is (IMHO) badly lawyered.

See [Confused about ill-formed templates](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/f411064574e99447) and [Compiling C++ templates as opposed to preprocessing them](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/78078fcf846f8859/d6736e18b373e5d6) (with Digital Mars fame [Walter Bright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33949/walter-bright))